# division-by-zero error occurs occasionally when using "act-walk" to find new living points in bilby

Tags: bilby

When I perform parameter estimation using sampler `dynesty` with the default `act-walk` method to find new points from the constrained prior, division-by-zero errors are occasionally thrown and terminate sampling process.

I am using the settings as below

```
15:37 bilby INFO    : Using sampler Dynesty with kwargs {'nlive': 2048, 'bound': 'live', 'sample': 'act-walk', 'periodic': None, 'reflective': None, 'update_interval': 600, 'first_update': None, 'npdim': None, 'rstate': None, 'queue_size': 72, 'pool': None, 'use_pool': None, 'live_points': None, 'logl_args': None, 'logl_kwargs': None, 'ptform_args': None, 'ptform_kwargs': None, 'gradient': None, 'grad_args': None, 'grad_kwargs': None, 'compute_jac': False, 'enlarge': None, 'bootstrap': None, 'walks': 100, 'facc': 0.2, 'slices': None, 'fmove': 0.9, 'max_move': 100, 'update_func': None, 'ncdim': None, 'blob': False, 'save_history': False, 'history_filename': None, 'maxiter': None, 'maxcall': None, 'dlogz': 0.1, 'logl_max': inf, 'n_effective': None, 'add_live': True, 'print_progress': True, 'print_func': <bound method Dynesty._print_func of <bilby.core.sampler.dynesty.Dynesty object at 0x7f0fc6a44160>>, 'save_bounds': False, 'checkpoint_file': None, 'checkpoint_every': 60, 'resume': False}
15:37 bilby INFO    : Checkpoint every check_point_delta_t = 600s
15:37 bilby INFO    : Using dynesty version 2.1.2
15:37 bilby INFO    : Using the bilby-implemented rwalk sampling tracking the autocorrelation function and thinning by 2 with maximum length 30000
15:37 bilby INFO    : Setting up multiproccesing pool with 72 processes
```

The error information is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hydrogen/miniconda3/envs/lisabeta-bilby/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/home/hydrogen/miniconda3/envs/lisabeta-bilby/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 48, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "/home/hydrogen/miniconda3/envs/lisabeta-bilby/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bilby/core/sampler/dynesty_utils.py", line 197, in __call__
    self.build_cache()
  File "/home/hydrogen/miniconda3/envs/lisabeta-bilby/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bilby/core/sampler/dynesty_utils.py", line 326, in build_cache
    accept = max(accept // n_found, 1)
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

I tried to adjust sampler settings and found that it seems more likely to trigger this problem if the `maxmcmc` is small.

By reading the source code of `ACTTrackingRWalk` class, I'm wondering the error maybe caused by the reason that althrough the chains are expect to have 50 times the autocorrelation length, if `act` is close to `maxmcmc` (e.g. `act` < `maxmcmc` < `act` * `nact`), the [`while` loop](https://git.ligo.org/lscsoft/bilby/-/blob/master/bilby/core/sampler/dynesty_utils.py#L243) is truncated by `maxmcmc`, after the loop the chain has only points less than one thinning factor (`act`*`nact`). So there is not a single point in the thinned chain. Whereas if we set a very large `maxmcmc`, it may leads to very inefficient CPU usage when using multiple cores in sampling.

1. Is this error a bug or caused by my improper sampler settings?
2. According to the [document](https://lscsoft.docs.ligo.org/bilby/dynesty-guide.html#bilby-specific-implementation-details), *"With this method, nact=2 often gives good results, however, in some cases, a larger value may be required"*, what are the cases we need to concern the non-default `nact` value?
3. How to determine the proper sampler settings, such as `maxmcmc` etc. Are these settings need to be tuned according to features of posterior distribution?

Answer (score -1):

> By reading the source code of `ACTTrackingRWalk` class, I'm wondering the error maybe caused by the reason that althrough the chains are expect to have 50 times the autocorrelation length, if act is close to `maxmcmc` (e.g. `act` < `maxmcmc` < `act` * `nact`), the while loop is truncated by `maxmcmc`, after the loop the chain has only points less than one thinning factor (`act`*`nact`). So there is not a single point in the thinned chain. Whereas if we set a very large `maxmcmc`, it may leads to very inefficient CPU usage when using multiple cores in sampling.

I think this is a good observation. However, I have not come across a `maxmcmc` setting in the `dynesty` sampler settings.
Usually with a non-trivial posterior shape that you might be expecting to obtain, `n_act` between 10-25 is a good choice and works reasonably well (given `npoints` >= 2000).

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: This would probably be more appropriate as a comment to the poster's question rather than an answer itself.  If you have supporting information or have found this as a solution yourself, please edit to clarify.